# How to remove custom field duplicates from Wordpress query

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Custom post is a store. Each city has few stores. 
I need to display list of cities taken from custom field in custom post, but I'd like to remove duplicates. Any help would be great.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 
array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_type' => 'store',
'meta_key' => 'city',
'orderby'          => 'meta_value',
'order'            => 'ASC',
)
);
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_field('city'  ) . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
} else {

}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier if you use a custom taxonomy for cities, wordpress has tax query which can filter them.

Comment: I'm new into this. That was obvious but to all but me :)

Comment: Well experts were also newbie once :)